# Java variables not available in different methods within class - newbie

Tags: java, variables, methods, declaration

I'm new to Java and I looked everywhere but I'm not getting a simple concept.

I declare two variables as int. I want the two variables to be global to all methods.
In my first method, I want to get the value of the first variable from user input.
Then I want that new value available, recognized, and called by the second method. However, every time the first method ends, the value of the variable is set back to 0, and the second method does not find the value the user gave to it in the first method input. What am I doing wrong? Do I need to declare my variables differently? Do I need to declare my methods differently? Thanks for your help!

```
import acm.program.*;

public class FindRange extends ConsoleProgram {

int num1;
int num2;

public void run() {

    println("This program finds the largest and smallest numbers.");

    getNum1();
    getNum2();
    // getNumUntilZero();
}

public void getNum1() {

    int num1 = readInt("?:");
    if (num1 == 0) { //do not accept 0 for first number
        println("Please try again without 0.");
        getNum1();
    }

}

public void getNum2() {
    int num2 = readInt("?:");
    if (num2 == 0) { //if 2nd number is 0, print 1st num as high and low nums
        println("Biggest number:" + num1);
        println("Smallest number:" + num1);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: you are redeclaring `num1`variable as well as `num2` variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you do    `int num1 = readInt("?:");` inside method getNum1(), its a local variable stored in stack . it does not refer to global variable  (declared as instance variable )which you want to refer

So do it like this:

```
public void getNum1() {
    num1 = readInt("?:");
    if (num1 == 0) { // do not accept 0 for first number
        println("Please try again without 0.");
        getNum1();
    }
}

public void getNum2() {
     num2 = readInt("?:");
    if (num2 == 0) { // if 2nd number is 0, print 1st num as high and low nums
        println("Biggest number:" + num1);
        println("Smallest number:" + num1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow I just had to remove <b>int</b> num1 ... in my method huh? I guess if I put int in there again, I'm re-declaring the variable? Thanks!

Comment: yes. you are right that when put int in there again, you are decalring the local variable

Answer (score 0):

actually you have created new variable inside method. so not actually assigning values to the class variables, but to method variable:
so change

```
   int num2 = readInt("?:");
```

to

```
  num2 = readInt("?:");
```

and

```
   int num1 = readInt("?:");
```

to

```
  num1 = readInt("?:");
```

Comment: Wow this site is incredible, I received the same response from multiple people pretty much instantaneously - thanks! I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

You redeclare a local variable called the same thing. This should give an IDE warning along of the lines of "local variable hides a field". So in the scope of the method there is *another* `numX`.

You need to reference the instance variable and not declare a new variable:

```
public void getNumX() {
    numX = readInt("?:");
    //...
}
```

You see I have removed the `int` declaration so that this now assigns the value to `numX` rather than to a local variable.

Comment: Wow this site is incredible, I received the same response from multiple people pretty much instantaneously - thanks! I understand now.